# Same code different result on different computers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can run these code correctly on my two computers, IOS, WINDOWS, but it can just find 98 names on my company's computer, Linux. And they all use python 2.7

```
import requests, bs4  
index_url = 'http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/druginfo/herb_All.html'

def get_urls():
    response = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    #print(response.)
    return [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.section-body a[href^=]')]
print(len(get_urls()))
```

Comment: Is everything the same version? I.e. Python and modules' versions? How many names should it find?

Comment: it should find 176 names. They all use Python 2.7. Will the different python cause this problem?

Comment: When you say IOS do you mean OSX (or whatever the current desktop version is) or do you mean your iPhone?

Comment: Your Linux computer might have a different version of BeautifulSoup. Try updating it if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps make sure that you are using the same parser and maybe specify which html parser you are using in your code that way when you run it on different machine it will know which one to use.

```
BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")
```

There is more info about this in the documentation.